# VBAT_BB and VBAT_RF in Quectel EC200u

Tags: pcb-design, power-electronics, embedded, gpio

I am designing a pcb for Quectel EC200U. It has been given to use two separate voltage domains for its VBAT_RF and VBAT_BB pins. What if i use a single power plate of 4v with one 100uF tantallum, one 100nF and one 10F capacitor for the four pins?

Comment: Quectel has very responsive technical support. I’d suggest you contact them with your question.

Answer (score 0):

The [datasheet](https://evelta.com/content/datasheets/027-EC200UCNAA.pdf) describes in chapter 3.7 that the power supply from an external application has to be a single voltage source.

The manufacturer recommends for each of the two power domains a 100μF low ESR cap, and 100 nF, 33 pF and 10 pF ceramic caps.

[image]